# It's about IPv6 where I don't understand the prefix

Tags: integration, system, ipv6

What do the remaining three prefixes mean after the provider prefix and before the subnet prefix?

I marked a question with an arrow

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mT8xI.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prefix like "/3" is [Classless Inter Domain Routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) which is used to specify IP addresses range.

Comment: Thanks, got it and got a 1 as a grade.